# Remove the default 'Display xx more...' from profiles

Tags: feature-request, jobs, profile-page

I don't know about others, but some of the people I send a link to careers.SO.com/kenny aren't smart enough to click on 'Display xx more...'. Can we at least get a URL that doesn't show a page with those links?

Comment: Do you really want to be working for someone who can't navigate the internet?

Comment: @James, I guess you've never talked to a headhunter or my parents. ;)